# How do I add signalR to a background service in different project?

Tags: .net, signalr, asp.net-core-6.0, background-service

I have a working signal R in my MVC .net core 6.

I have a background service in my MVC project which calls my signalR hub and updates all my pages. I have moved this background service to its own project and now its not working. Is this even possible?

MVC .Net Cor 6 project:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

background service in a different project:

```
public class CalculatorConsumer : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<CalculatorConsumer> _logger;
    private readonly ISubscriptionClient _subscriptionClient;
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;

    public CalculatorConsumer(
        ILogger<CalculatorConsumer> logger,
        ISubscriptionClient subscriptionClient,
        IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _subscriptionClient = subscriptionClient;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {Time}", DateTime.Now);
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"10");
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HubConnectionBuilder` to creat a hubconnection to call a remote hub URL. You will not need inject `ChatHub` in the seperate worker service project. Because you don't have it there, it's in the server.

In the worker service project, install package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` first .(sometimes you may need to resinstall this package)
Based on your code, you could modify as following

```
    public class CalculatorConsumer : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CalculatorConsumer> _logger;


        public CalculatorConsumer(ILogger<CalculatorConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        private List<string> messages = new List<string>(); 
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {

            var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:7218/chatHub").Build();   //change the URL to your server hub URL
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();


            hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
            {
                var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
                messages = encodedMsg;
            });

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {Time}", DateTime.Now);
                await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", "workerservice", "10");
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);         
            }
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
```

Reference:
[Create a Client in .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#connect-to-a-hub)
[How to add client to blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server#add-razor-component-code-for-chat-1)